# Create new matrix based on row and column subscripts

Tags: matlab

Given the following 4x6 matrix `A`:

```
A = [
10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31 32 33
];
```

and two variables containing the row and column subscripts (`r` and `c`, respectively):

```
r = [
1 1 1
1 1 1
3 3 3
3 3 3
4 4 4
];

c = [
1 3 6
1 2 4
1 2 6
1 4 5
1 5 6
];
```

I want to create a new 5x3 matrix `B` that takes each row and column combination from `r` and `c` such that:

```
B = [
10 12 15
10 11 13
22 23 27
22 25 26
28 32 33
];
```

Note that element `B(1,1)` is derived by using `r(1,1)` as the row subscript and `c(1,1)` as the column subscript.  Element `B(1,2)` takes `r(1,2)` and `c(1,2)` as the row and column subscripts.  And so on...

I can solve this problem using a nested for loop, but the actual application I am working on has very large matrices and this method leads to a significant bottleneck.  Are there better (read: quicker) alternatives?

The `for` loop for reference:

```
B = NaN(size(r,1),size(c,2));
for row=1:size(r,1)
    for col=1:size(c,2)
        B(row,col) = A(r(row,col),c(row,col));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can index 2D matrices with a single index value that is the concatenation of the columns -- like turning your matrix into a vector by column-by-column. For example, you could access `A(4,2)` simply using `A(8)`.

So, all you need to do is create a new matrix of indices and then access A at those values:

```
% input data array
A = [10 11 12 13 14 15;
16 17 18 19 20 21;
22 23 24 25 26 27;
28 29 30 31 32 33];

% number of rows
N_rows = size(A,1);

% row indices
r = [1 1 1;
1 1 1;
3 3 3;
3 3 3;
4 4 4];

% column indices
c = [1 3 6;
1 2 4;
1 2 6;
1 4 5;
1 5 6];

% element indices
idx = (c - 1)*N_rows + r;

% new indexed array
B = A(idx);

% display outputs
disp(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sub2ind](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function to convert subscripts (r,c) to linear indices ('single index value').

If you need the reverse conversion use ind2sub.

Comment: This is dedicated way to go, but you should include at least some code, to make that answer upvoteworthy. This way its rather a comment.